# Is there a way to disable all notifications on the iPhone in one step?

Tags: iphone, notifications

Is there a way, when doing screen recording (for online gameplay, for example), to disable all notifications in one step, so that it won't interfere with the screen recording?

Details: It can be done by turning off all notifications for 35 apps one by one, and when done with screen recording, turn them on one by one again -- but it will be 70 steps total this way.

I want to disable any notification at all, including the one that slide down showing "no preview" content -- I want to disable those as well -- everything.

Comment: Do Not Disturb, or Airplane mode? [Can't test, not on iOS 11]

Comment: the phone is already in do not disturb mode, but the message will still slide down and show on the top of the screen

Comment: @Tetsujin mentioned Airplane mode. Good solution unless you need to be online for your recording.

Answer (score 6):

**Do Not Disturb** does also hide notifications and you can ***customize*** it like allow incoming calls from favorites or everyone.

When the device is locked, it won't light up the screen when receiving a message. But by enabling 'Always' on the bottom of the Do Not Disturb setting page, it will also block the notifications when your device is unlocked.

So they won't pop up on your screen, you can only see them by opening the notification center.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set notification preview to never
2. Enable DND
3. Remove apps and disable notifications that don't respect the above settings.

For some testing you might be able to disable cellular and then block the APNS servers or all internet or just Apple's servers, but local notifications will still trigger since they are designed to do so.

Your best bet for controlling a demo is to control all the apps and settings closely rather than using a fully loaded device with many sources of distraction or interruption.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204321).  It looks like you need to make sure DND is set to `Always`:

## Change Your Settings

If you don't want to be disturbed at a certain time, you can set a schedule. Tap `Settings > Do Not Disturb` and turn on `Scheduled`. Then set a time.

You can also choose when you want to receive alerts, calls, and notifications:

- Allow Calls From: Allow calls from everyone, no one, your favorites, or specific contact groups stored on your device or iCloud.
- Repeated Calls: If someone calls you twice within three minutes, the call won't be silenced.
- **Silence**: Choose to **silence calls and notifications always** or only when the device is locked.

Comment: like I said, the notifications can be silent, but they still slide down from the top of the screen, affecting the screen recording

Comment: That's all I could find from Apple.  You already know you can silence individual apps so that might be your only option right now.   I would also recommend leaving Apple [product feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) and requesting this feature.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, but Apple makes the software so don’t blame the messenger here.

Comment: How come you are not saying anything about the two people who downvoted this question?

Comment: @bmike There are tons of information out there on the Internet. As a messenger, are you to bring the correct answer here or can you bring anything that seems related here? Ask Different is for you to bring in the correct solution. If your solution is not correct, and you are the messenger, why do you bring that material in?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Question voting is a lot more loose and I can't fault someone for feeling it's unclear or just a yes/no question. For instance - the update at the top makes it more confusing to me and in the end - you know one answer is turn off each app that you don't want notifications or uninstall those apps. You did do a very good job not making it into a rant - why doesn't apple make this easier. +1 for that. My guess is you'll get + votes now that the title is far less confusing - good edit there.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 As to correct - the stack exchange model is to have information, hopefully sourced and let the voting determine correctness. As moderators, We do not remove wrong answers - but we do comment on them and vote on them we do provide more correct answers so that voting surfaces the best and most correct ideas. I'm happy to discuss more on [meta] or [chat] if you'd like

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed a new Mac app that states it stops all notification messages.

[Muzzle](https://muzzleapp.com) is free and according to the developer:

> Muzzle was born in a group iMessage thread. See, Brian was screensharing with a client when Josh sent him a message about that client, which macOS delightfully showed...to the client. Bad times were had by all. But Brian and Josh knew a Mac developer. And that Mac developer had a working build of Muzzle in their hands five hours later.

I'm not saying this app will solve all your problems, I just saw it and thought I'd pass it on.

Comment: This is cool and probably should be posted to the thread that asks for macOS notification control instead of iOS screen recording and iOS screen notifications.